# How can Automate Or Bypass Text-Based captcha in Cypress

Tags: testing, automation, cypress, captcha, text-based

I can't automate or bypass the Text-Based captcha in Cypress.
Click here to open this image
[This Type of captcha I want to automate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pgQI.png)

I try to use cy.pause() Command and enter manually the captcha but it was repeatedly changed the captcha. I want to automate or bypass this captcha

Please, anyone, help me with this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't automate captcha , that's the whole point of it (so other automated bots can't pass through).

The other solution would be to disable this captcha feature in test environment.

See this article for further assistance https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-handle-captcha-in-selenium

Comment: Thank You for your answer but I am working on Cypress then how can I disable this captcha feature?

Comment: No matter what automation framework you use, but the principle is the same

Comment: I tried but not working to automate because the captcha text always change even we write the captcha and then click Still that captcha is changed